# how do i modify the get number function so that in the next attempt i will get new number

Tags: javascript

```
"use strict"

function getNumber(){
   return (Math.floor(Math.random()*100+1));
}

var compNumber = getNumber();
var chances = 0;
let playAgain = false;

do {
    playAgain = false;
    var userNumber = prompt("Enter your number.");
        userNumber = Number(userNumber);

    if(userNumber>compNumber){
        console.log("your number is greater.");
    }
    else if(userNumber<compNumber){
        console.log("your number is lesser.");
    }
    else{
        console.log(`congratulations you guessed it right and your score is ${100-chances}`);
            playAgain = confirm("do you want to play again ?");
        if(playAgain){
            getNumber();
            chances = 0;
        }
    }
    chances++
}while(userNumber!== compNumber && chances<=100 || playAgain);
```

now this program giving me same random number after i confirm to play again but i wanted another random number how could i achieve this

Comment: `if(playAgain){
            getNumber();
            chances = 0;
        }` you call `getNumber()` but you don't set it to a variable.

Comment: ohh yeah yeah now i got it thank you for your help it means a lot i am begineer in this field. btw do you think i can remove that playAgain from the while brackets beacause i guess this doesn,t doing anything without it program running fine.

Answer (score 0):

```js
"use strict"

function getNumber(){
   return (Math.floor(Math.random()*100+1));
}

var compNumber = getNumber();
var chances = 0;
let playAgain = false;

do {
    playAgain = false;
    var userNumber = prompt("Enter your number.");
        userNumber = Number(userNumber);

    if(userNumber>compNumber){
        console.log("your number is greater.");
    }
    else if(userNumber<compNumber){
        console.log("your number is lesser.");
    }
    else{
        console.log(`congratulations you guessed it right and your score is ${100-chances}`);
            playAgain = confirm("do you want to play again ?");
        if(playAgain){
            compNumber = getNumber();
            chances = 0;
        }
    }
    chances++
}while(userNumber!== compNumber && chances<=100);
```